# Qt Android: Put videos inside app directory files

Tags: android, qt, qml

I have around 10 video files in the sizes of 10 MB each. I want to have them inside the `/data/user/0/org.my.app/files`. Somehow they need to be included in the `.apk` and installed here.

Right now they are living in this structure in Qt project:

```
DISTFILES += \
    assets/video/video1.mp4
```

The goal is to be able to play the videos using

```
Video {
  source: appPath + "/assets/video/video1.mp4"
}
```

The ideal way is just using `.qrc` but it has been problems before when putting videos there.

Comment: Have you tried reading this? https://falsinsoft.blogspot.com/2017/01/qt-creator-include-additional-files.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With video, it's usually impractical to try to make it a resource since the size of the QRC will explode and result in long compile times and a large executable.

I've had luck delivering videos with a Qt Android app by using the native Java AssetManager: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager

You'll need to use a CustomActivity in Java-land and integrate with it using JNI as demonstrated here: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtandroidextras-customactivity-example.html

Or as @splaytreez points out you can use Qt's builtin support for Android Assets as documented here: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/porting-to-android.html

Also, depending on the size of your video and what it does to your APK size, you may want to use the AAB bundle as discussed here: https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/

Comment: Thanks, I ended up going with the Qt assets variant for now. For reference to be able to load the file use `source: "assets:/video1.mp4"`